# how to write select statement for a function in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am not writing the actual total function here as it is too big

My function name is spell_number.

For Oracle :`create or replace function spell_number(n in number) returns varchar2`

For PostgreSQL :`create or replace function spell_number(n bigint) returns text`

For oracle I can use:
SELECT spell_number (53734555555585) FROM DUAL;

In PostgreSQL how can be the select statement like ?
I have searched for replacement of dual in PostgreSQL but not getting the actual thing I want.

Comment: `SELECT spell_number(53734555555585);`

Comment: In postgres, the `FROM` clause is *more or less* optional, so you don't need the "syntactic sugar" `FROM dual` pseudo-table-reference clause.

Comment: So you can select (not only functions, but) any expression that does not refer any table, such as `select 2 * 3 +4 AS result;` , and the answer will be 10.

Comment: @joop - I am not sure about the characterization of `dual` as a **pseudo**-table (or the reference to it as a "pseudo-table-reference" - it isn't clear how you meant that). `dual` is a legitimate table in the `sys` schema, it is not a made-up name. You can actually change that table: add rows to it, etc. (which will screw up everything you do in Oracle, but it is possible).

Comment: Yes, I know. It is possible to emulate that in Postgres, too (one table with exactly one row, and zero columns) but it is not needed. But it still is a semantic hack to solve the syntactic rigidity. (of SQL, that is) And I call it *pseudo* because it doesn't (shouldn't) *behave* like an ordinary table. You cannot insert into it, for example.

Comment: What is your return value type?  Some Postgres functions can be executed as "select func_name()", whereas some return pseudo-table, cursor, result, etc types and must be included as a table declaration, a la "select * from func_name()"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT * from spell_number (53734555555585);
```